# Is there a way using SVNKit to get the names of the changed methods?

Tags: svn, svnkit

Is there a way using SVNKit to get the names of the changed methods rather than the whole contents?

Right now I can use SVNKit to get SVN log, but I want to get the changed methods in some SVN version.

How can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

No. Subversion just manages data, it doesn't understand what that data is or how it works. It doesn't know the difference between a method in Java source or a WHERE clause in a SQL statement or a line of plain text in a README file.

You can get a diff, and then parse the diff yourself to extract methods, but that's all. Subversion can't do more than tell you what bytes/lines changed.